# How do you make the camera's field of view bigger, so it can see more

Tags: camera

On blender, I am trying to render something. However, the camera is too small? Somebody help!!
[image]

Comment: Change the resolution in the render panel

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the resolution of your render.

1. Click on the camera icon in the propery menu.
2. Change the X & Y value in the tab Dimension.

[image]